# Same UIalertview for multi button, multi view

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

In my application ,i having 4 UIbuttons .On click each button showing same alert view contains learn and play option,while clicking alert view, want to show the different view depends on the uibutton selection.Here my code for alert view. please help me to perform diffrent view on click option.

```
-(IBAction)animals
{
UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];     
[alert1 show];
}
-(IBAction)birds
{
UIAlertView *alert2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
[alert2 show];    
}
-(IBAction)direct
{ 
UIAlertView *alert3=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
[alert3 show];
}
-(IBAction)fruit
{
UIAlertView *alert4=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
[alert4 show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"LEARN"]) 
{


    animallearn *aview=[[animallearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"animallearn" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];
}
else if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"PLAY"])
{ 
    birdslearn *bview=[[birdslearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"birdslearn" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bview animated:YES];
 }
else
{
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: But here u hav made different alert views ... please be more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)animals
{
    UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];     
    alert1.tag = 1;  
    [alert1 show];
}
-(IBAction)birds
{
    UIAlertView *alert2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
    alert2.tag = 2;  
    [alert2 show];    
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if(alertView.tag == 1)
    {
            //animal alert
    }
    else if(alertView.tag == 2)
    {
            //birds alert
    }
    // and so on......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a tag attribute for UIAlertView. It's an int. You should assign your tag with different values.

```
-(IBAction)direct
{ 
  UIAlertView *alert3=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
  [alert3 setTag:3];
  [alert3 show];
}
```

And then clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method you should observe the tag of your current alert view:

```
if(alertView.tag == 3) //etc ...
```

And I don't know if you're using ARC but if not you must add an autorelease when you instantiate your alert view.

Comment: if am clicking on other button what will be the tag value?

Comment: I just give you an example of one alert. Apply the same method to other alert. With a formula : Alert_N *alert= ....; [alert setTag:N];

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `UIAlertView` globally then you can compare them with `UIAlertView` delegates object like this-

```
 UIAlertView *alert1;
 UIAlertView *alert2;

-(IBAction)animals
{
   alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];     
   [alert1 show];
}

-(IBAction)birds
{
    alert2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil]; 
    [alert2 show];    
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if(alertView ==alert1)
  {
    if (buttonIndex==1)
    {

    }
    if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {

    }
 }    

if(alertView == alert2)
{
    if (buttonIndex==1) 
    {


    }
}
```

According to this you would not need tags  :) Simply use the conditions

Comment: No you can't use this because alert1 is no more referenced.

Comment: Now i have edited my answer i forgot to say that alert view are global not local .... :)

Comment: I hope you are using @property to declare them ;)

Comment: I think it's the best way to way a clean memory management but yes it's up to every one.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)animals
{
    UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
    [alert1 show];
    [alert1 setTag:101];
 }
-(IBAction)birds
{
    UIAlertView *alert2=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
    [alert2 show];
    [alert2 setTag:102];
 }


-(IBAction)direct
{
    UIAlertView *alert3=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
    [alert3 show];
    [alert3 setTag:103];
 }


-(IBAction)fruit
{
    UIAlertView *alert4=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"LEARN",@"PLAY",@"CANCEL",nil];
    [alert4 show];
    [alert4 setTag:104];
 }


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    // learn has indextag = 0 ,play =1 cancel = 2

    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if (alertView.tag == 101) {



    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            animallearn *aview=[[animallearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"animallearn" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];

            break;
        case 1:
            birdslearn *bview=[[birdslearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"birdslearn" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:bview animated:YES];

            break;

        case 2:
            return;
            break;



        default:
            break;
    }

         }

    if (alertView.tag == 102) {



        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                animallearn *aview=[[animallearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"animallearn" bundle:nil];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:aview animated:YES];

                break;
            case 1:
                birdslearn *bview=[[birdslearn alloc]initWithNibName:@"birdslearn" bundle:nil];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:bview animated:YES];

                break;

            case 2:
                return;
                break;



            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    // perform the same for tag = 103 and 104
}
```